# Resize before convert or convert before resize?

Tags: resize, file-conversion

Is it better to resize an image before converting it from png to jpg, or to convert it before resizing it?

Same for cropping instead of resizing (but I guess that cropping before or after makes no diff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resize prior to *any* lossy compression - this gets you the best quality result for the intended pixel dimensions.

Lossy compression like `.jpg` save space by calculating relationships and change of pixel arrays, so for best effect, you want to do all resizing in the base non-compressed image, and you'll get better results from the placing of the compressed image if the compression "knows" the final pixel size.

Comment: so it can be generalized as "do any image modification prior to any lossy compression", right?

Comment: @pedrotester Always. That's the thumbrule.

Comment: hmm and I suppose it's better to resize only once, and not to resize twice consecutively? example: from 100% to 20% instead of 100% to 50% to 20%